# Onchange and select inside a form using javascript does not work. If placed outside the form it works

Tags: javascript, html, forms, select, onchange

I am creating a form that shows the changes in realtime. When I placed my codes inside a form, it stopped working.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<form id="selectform" name="myform" action="dothis.php" method="post">
 <select id="selectProfileIcon" name="newentry" onchange="selectProfileIcon()">
    <option value="aboutme">ABOUT ME</option>
    <option value="aboutus">ABOUT US</option>
    <option value="alert">ALERT</option>
    <option value="services">SERVICES</option>
    <option value="deals">DEALS</option>
    <option value="events">EVENTS</option>
    <option value="hotdeals">HOT DEALS</option>
    <option value="hotpicks">MY PICKS</option>
    <option value="newitems">NEW ITEMS</option>
    <option value="onsale">ON SALE</option>
    <option value="promo">PROMOTION</option>
    <option value="recall">RECALL</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="profileIcon">ABOUT ME</div>
```

and here is the Javascript

```
function selectProfileIcon() {
var ta = document.getElementById("selectProfileIcon");
var div = document.getElementById("profileIcon");
if (ta.value === "aboutme") {
    div.innerHTML = "ABOUT ME";
} else if (ta.value === "aboutus") {
    div.innerHTML = "ABOUT US";
} else if (ta.value === "alert") {
    div.innerHTML = "ALERT";
} else if (ta.value === "services") {
    div.innerHTML = "SERVICES";
} else if (ta.value === "deals") {
    div.innerHTML = "DEALS";
} else if (ta.value === "events") {
    div.innerHTML = "EVENTS";
} else if (ta.value === "hotdeals") {
    div.innerHTML = "HOT DEALS";
} else if (ta.value === "hotpicks") {
    div.innerHTML = "MY PICKS";
} else if (ta.value === "newitems") {
    div.innerHTML = "NEW ITEMS";
} else if (ta.value === "onsale") {
    div.innerHTML = "ON SALE";
} else if (ta.value === "promo") {
    div.innerHTML = "PROMOTION";
} else if (ta.value === "recall") {
    div.innerHTML = "RECALL";
} else {
    div.innerHTML = "No selection";
}
}
```

Here's the code in jsfiddle: [JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/Kontakme/2x02qzto/)

Try removing the form tags and it works. putting it back disables it.

If you have a substitute code , it is most welcomed. I'm really curious why it doesn't work when inside the form. Thanks!

Comment: That javascript makes my eyes bleed.

Comment: I'm a novice on this one and learning to code. If it works. it's fine with me. If you know how to streamline a multi nested statement, your suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the `<form>` but the fact that your element ID is the same as your function name. Rename the ID or the function.

**HTML**

```
<select id="test" name="taurus" onchange="selectProfileIcon()">
```

**JavaScript**

```
function selectProfileIcon() {
    var ta = document.getElementById("test");
    // etc...
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2x02qzto/2/)

Comment: Thanks Hazaart.  I was reviewing my code and indeed it was the problem. I did not notice at first that I have similar IDs and function name.  THanks for the answers. it works now.

Comment: No problem :-) Please select my reply as answer if it solved your problem